# Error java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, awt

I don't understand why my code isn't working, trying to print a rectangle in my `JFrame`, but keep ending up with an error on `f.add(p);`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SPEL{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(50,75,100,50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setLocation(100,100);
        f.setTitle("SPEL");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SPEL p = new SPEL();
        f.add(p);//error
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"an error"* Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: The SPEL class is not a Java Swing component, so it can't be added to the JFrame.

Comment: Tip: Add @GilbertLeBlanc (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify them of a new comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `extends` something, for example:

```
public class SPEL extends JPanel {
```

You can add `@Override` to reduce the chance of this kind of  mistake

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
```

Comment: And super.paintComponent(g) and starting the UI within the EDT

Comment: `@Override` Now that's a +1

Comment: *"but how do i add the "g.drawRect" to the jframe"*  Instead of painting to a top level container, it is generally preferable to paint to a `JPanel`.  So stick to the way stated in the answer, make the class `extends JPanel`.

Comment: thanks, real beginner at this. missed the whole extends bit haha

Answer (score 1):

try this! :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SPEL extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
        Rectangle b = new Rectangle(50, 75, 100, 50);
        g2d.draw(b);
        g2d.fill(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setLocation(100, 100);
        f.setTitle("SPEL");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SPEL p = new SPEL();
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

- `extends JPanle`
- `@Override`
- `Using Graphics2D`
- `g2d.fill(Shape s)`